# Obtener el valor de un listado de input para pasarlo por ajax

Tags: php, jquery

Hice un recorrido con la data preparada con 158 de ellos e almacenado en el id del imput tipo hidden, y le pase como valor el id de mi data que va desde 2 hasta 158, quiero obtener cada valor al darle click a la caja padre.
mi phtml

```
<div id="listar_provedor"class="container"> 
<?php foreach ($this->data_pro as $key => $value): ?>

<div id="caja_content" class="w25">
    <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" name="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>"   >
    <div class="img">
        <img src="http://68.183.166.7/global/images_v2.0/proveedores/<?php echo(empty($value['imagen'])?'19880818.png':$value['imagen']) ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="bloque">
        <p><?php echo $value['razon_social']; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $value['contacto']; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $value['celular'] ?></p>
        <p> Pdos(0) </p>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como lo tienes, vas a generar 158 `<div>`s con id `caja_content`. Esto no debe ser así, ya que por definición, un identificador debe ser único.

Cambia el atributo `id` por `class` y añade la clave como data-id:

```html
<div data-id="<?php echo htmlentities($value['id']) ?>" class="caja_content w25">
```

Al final, añade tu código javascript para leer elid cuando se clique en el `<div>`. Utilizando jquery:

```html
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.caja_content', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    // usa el id aquí para tu llamada ajax
    alert('ID: ' + id);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu corrección y por la ayuda me sirvio de mucho.

Comment: De nada @david. En tal caso, podrías aceptar la respuesta como válida? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @jotaelesalinas podrias ayudarme con una pregunta que publique, en la cual quiero previsualizar una imagen y obtenerla en una variable para pasarla por ajax y asi crear o actualizarla solo que no es el unico campo que insertare o actualizare sino otros campos más, gracias por tú tiempo

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/379678/186819